# jQuery UI Slider Range-ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, uislider

I'm using the jQuery UI slider and had no problems with it in the past. However, now, when I set the slider range to "max" (or "min") and change the value of the slider by dragging, the range part of the ui (with the class "range-ui") does not resize with it! So i don't see the colored part of the current range. I'm pretty stuck, anyone know what the reason for this may be?

How it should be:

[image: How It should be]

How it is:

[image: How it is]

Comment: Can you replicate this on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.com)?

Comment: Ok, I did, and it seems to work there. http://jsfiddle.net/wXWzy/. Though, I still don't see the difference between what I'm doing in my web-app and what I'm doing on jsFiddle... I realize that isn't very helpful. Though, I think it's pretty strange that everything the javascript of the jQuery slider should do works, except for resizing the range-ui...

Comment: Then it's your other `css` declarations to blaim. :)

Comment: Thanks for the input, but when I drag the handle and then look at the source code (with the chrome developer tools) I see that the range-ui div isn't being resized. When I resize the div programmatically (with the developer tools) I do see the grey range-ui area...

Comment: give "background: none" css property to the element containing the slider.