# jQuery UI Slider Color issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-slider, jquery-slider

I am trying to get a slider work with costumed background

How ever it shows in my web site with out any background colour

The issue is same as the link below
[jQuery UI Slider Range-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299454/jQuery-ui-slider-range-ui)

Already try to added range: 'min' in my code but still not work

```
$("#sliderME").slider({

    min: 7.9, 
    max: 14.0,
    range: "min",
    step: 0.1, 
    value: 11.2   
});
```

Please Help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723633/changing-the-color-of-a-jquery-ui-slider-as-you-slide-it

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery UI Slider Range-ui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299454/jquery-ui-slider-range-ui)